# http.client.HTTPConnection() and cookiejar Python 3

Tags: python, http, cookies, screen-scraping

How to get cookies that php script sends to browser? I found that:

```
Create a cookiejar to store cookie
self.cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
# Create opener
self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(self.cj))
urllib.request.install_opener(self.opener)
```

It works only with

```
self.opener.open(url)
```

???? 
I need to store cookies with something like that:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("myurl")
conn.request("POST", url, "data=test", headers)
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at the requests library. It's more readible than Urllib. Also, cookies are pretty simple with requests. Here is the URL: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ Requests is compatible with python 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: Holy crap, how could i live without this? I would like to kiss you ;)